# Make a keypress "click" an html button

Tags: javascript, onclick, click, calculator, keypress

so I'm making a simple calculator. I have coded it with onclick as such:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".numbers").forEach((element) => {
  element.onclick = () => {
    inputNumbers(element);
  };
});

inputNumbers = (element) => {
  if (
    element.id === "decimalbtn" &&
    $display.innerText.includes(".") &&
    !equalPressed
  ) {
    $display.innerText = element.innerText;
// ....
```

and with the html looking like this:

```
<button id="4btn" class="numbers" value="4">4</button>
```

All i want to do, is make it so when i click say "4" on my keyboard, that it simulates clicking the 4 button.

I tried

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.key === "enter") {
    document.querySelector('*[data-op="equals"]').click();
  }
});
```

for the equals button, but for some reason it doesnt work. If i hit 8 + 2 then hit enter it gives me 22. I think it doesn't trigger the if statement and breaks.

Any pointers? Want to keep it vanilla JS, and i think would be easier to simulate an html button click than trying to implement keypreses into existing functions, but im all ears.

Comment: `if (event.key === "enter") { event.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: Sorry, where are you suggesting i put this? Like in what i have now but before the queryselector? -Just did it in that way and this didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is working:

```
 document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
if (e.key == "." || (e.key >= 0 && e.key <= 9)) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById(e.key + "btn").click();
} else if (e.key == "Enter" || e.key == "=") {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("equalsignbtn").click();
```

and i changed decimalbtn to .btn to work with this.